# Логи ошибок MySQL

Tags: логирование, mysql

Продолжаю разбираться со своим глючным сайтом. Решил посмотреть логи MySQL и вот, что я там нашел:

```
140128 15:12:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140128 15:12:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140128 15:12:45  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140128 15:12:46  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:12:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140128 15:15:54 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140128 15:15:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140128 15:15:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140128 15:15:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140128 15:15:56 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:15:59  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140128 15:16:00  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:00 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140128 15:16:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140128 15:16:00 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140128 15:16:00  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140128 15:16:01 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595695
ERROR: 1064  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE user ADD column Show_view_priv enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT ' at line 1
140128 15:16:01 [ERROR] Aborting

140128 15:16:01  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140128 15:16:02  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140128 15:16:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140128 15:16:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140128 15:16:02 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140128 15:16:03  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140128 15:16:04 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:04  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140128 15:16:05  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:05 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140128 15:16:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140128 15:16:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140128 15:16:05  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140128 15:16:06 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595695
ERROR: 1050  Table 'plugin' already exists
140128 15:16:06 [ERROR] Aborting

140128 15:16:06  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140128 15:16:07  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:07 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140128 15:16:08 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140128 15:16:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140128 15:16:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140128 15:16:09  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140128 15:16:10 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 1595695
140128 15:16:10 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140128 15:16:10 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140128 15:16:10 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140128 15:16:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140128 15:16:10 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Можете подсказать есть ли какие-то критические ошибки, которые желательно устранить в первую очередь? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нет ошибок. Все нормально, если обновлять mysql не решите. 
Один warning только есть: использование myisam-recover - и то, в данной версии работает корректно, но не рекомендуется для использования, потому что в дальнейшем от него будут отказываться.

Comment: дык а где ошибки? я только одну видел